# Problems with Vue JS Calling API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently just learning about Vue.js and i'm having a problem with calling an API. I have accessing this public API from https://swapi.co/api/people/ and i have problems when i'm accessing the films detail. I've got the films data but the data is piled up in the last array, and i don't know what to do. Hope you guys can help me :D

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'home',
    data: () => ({
        profiles: [],
        last_name_v: '',
        movies_urls: [],
        movies: [],
        movie_s: [],
        relateds: [],
        errors: [],
        datas: []
    }),

    created() {
        axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
            .then(response => {
                this.profiles = response.data.results.slice(0, 2);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.profiles.length; i++) {
                    var profile_val = this.profiles[i];
                    var full_name_o = profile_val.name;
                    var full_name_s = full_name_o.split(' ');
                    var last_name = full_name_s[full_name_s.length - 1];
                    profile_val['last_name'] = last_name;

                    var movie_urls = profile_val.films.slice(0, 4);
                    console.log(profile_val.films.slice(0, 4));
                    profile_val['movie_details'] = [];
                    for (var j = 0; j < movie_urls.length; j++) {
                        axios.get(movie_urls[j])
                            .then(response => {
                                profile_val.movie_details.push(response.data);
                            })
                            .catch(e => {
                                this.errors.push(e);
                            });
                    }
                    this.datas.push(profile_val);
                }
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post output as well

Comment: To clarify: What do you mean by "the data is piled up in the last array"? What is "the data"? What is "the last array"?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think the value of `profile_val` will be once all of the promises in your inner for loop resolve?

```
for (var j = 0; j < movie_urls.length; j++) {
    axios.get(movie_urls[j])
        .then(response => {
            profile_val.movie_details.push(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e);
        });
}
```

One of the simplest things you could do is move this out into a function and capture `profile_val` in a closure.

```
function fetchMovieDetails (profile_val, movie_url) {
    return axios.get(movie_url)
        .then(res => profile_val.movie_details.push(res.data));
}
```